# How to execute rbenv shell through a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, rbenv

My change_ruby_env.sh file looks something like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rbenv shell 1.9.3-p327
rbenv rehash

#execute something
rbenv shell 2.0.0-p451
rbenv rehash
```

---

And when I run this shell script like `sh change_ruby_env.sh` I get the following error:

```
rbenv: no such command `shell'
```

rbenv shell 1.9.3-p327/2.0.0-p451 works for me on interactive shell. I am not able to get it to work in a shell script.

Could anybody please tell me how to overcome this..

Comment: Shell scripts should start with `#!`. Your question shows only `!` -- is that a typo? Also, full path to `env` is usually `/usr/bin/env`. Verify that you're using correct path.

Comment: @ArtemB yup sorry, correcting it.

Comment: @ArtemB /usr/bin/env is the correct path , checked it out.

Comment: Did you export your PATH environment variable in your bashrc? Does this script have the correct PATH? is rbenv in the PATH?

Comment: @GriffinG yup PATH has rbenv , .rbenv/bin: and .rbenv/shims

Comment: @GriffinG rbenv shell works in the interactive shell , I want to make it work in a shell script. Sorry for the poor communication on my part.

Comment: @attu013 you may want to update your question with /usr/bin/env then.

Comment: @ArtemB made the change , but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following : eval "$(rbenv init -)" to my script solved this issue for me. I also have this line in my .bash_profile.